# How to implement this Lyrics API in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, api

I found a lyrics API at http://www.lyrdb.com/services/lws-tech.php. It basically returns a set of results upon being queried. I am not well versed with PHP to be frank, but I have a clue about this somewhat, that the result set returned needs to be stored in a String variable and then the song ID extracted from it that the user clicks on, to retrieve the lyrics via the song ID.

Can anyone help me in scripting this please! Appreciate your help so much :)

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, SO is aimed at specific questions, not coding things for you or writing entire books.  Try something, and then when you run into specific problems, if you can't figure them out on your, then consider posting on SO.  In it's current state, your question is way too broad.

Comment: How to access a service is a specific question - giving the man a curl or file_get_contents is not a big deal now is it?

Comment: I'm sorry if this violates any rules in SO, I'm new here actually, would keep that in mind @Corbin :).

Comment: @mplungjan No, it's not.  Maybe *specifically* how to access it, but this question involves not only accessing but also parsing.  And given how simple the API is, I believe it falls more into the realm of learning PHP than an actual question.  I suppose it is a simple enough question to answer, but I do not believe the question is in the spirit of SO.  Obviously people differ with me on that though.  (Also, for what it's worth, neither of the -1 is from me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No one can teach you PHP on SO. However to get you started you basically need two functions of PHP.

1. [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)
2. [split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php)

Below is a sample code which will do this for you:

```
abhinavsingh@ubuntu:~$ cat lyrdb.php 
<?php

$res = file_get_contents("http://webservices.lyrdb.com/lookup.php?q=we%20are%20the%20champions&for=trackname&agent=agent");
//echo $res;
$res = split(PHP_EOL, $res);
//print_r($res);
foreach($res as $k=>$v) {
    $v = split("\\\\", $v);
    //print_r($v);
    $lyr = file_get_contents("http://webservices.lyrdb.com/getlyr.php?q=".$v[0]);
    //echo $lyr;
}

?>
```

This fetches lyrics for all the results returned from first query.
You might just want to do it on limited set of data.

Comment: `split` is deprecated. In your case you do not even need a regex so use `explode()` instead! And your use of `PHP_EOL` is bad, possibly the website used `\n` but your PHP code might be running on a `\r\n` system (windows) where it would then break. Besides that, to get a file/web resource line-by-line, you can use `$res = file('http://...');`

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance Abhinav, that helped a lot in finding my way out in this! :)

Answer (score 1):

Start you off

```
$titles = explode("\n",file_get_contents("http://webservices.lyrdb.com/lookup.php?q=Elton+John&for=artist&agent=testservice"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your time in answering my query Sir, appreciate it:)